# Change a single float number in Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, decimal, rounding

I'm almost done with my assignment. However, I have to make only one small adjustment to my final data frame.
For the column "CL_Total" the first row number 157.580 has be changed to two decimals, not three. I only have to change this number.
Can anybody help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwA16.png)

The Data frame should look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuwCE.png)

The code I have now is this, but the number does not change in two decimals:

```
df_final['CL_total'].iloc[0] == df_final['CL_total'].iloc[0].round(2)
print(df_final.iloc[:6])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That column of your dataframe contains floats, and 157.850 and 157.85 are the same float. As far as I know, pandas will always show the same number of decimal places for all the values in a column of floats. If you want to manipulate the number of trailing zeroes like that, you'll need to convert the number to a strings:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'values': [15.58, 12.345]})
>>> print(df)
   values
0  15.580
1  12.345
>>> df['values'].iloc[0] = str(df['values'].iloc[0].round(2))
>>> print(df)
  values
0  15.58
1 12.345
```

A pandas dataframe is really a store of data, not a visual product like a spreadsheet. So if you want to get a dataframe in shape to be used that way, converting things to strings is a good idea.

Comment: Hi Jacob, I get the following error when I copy and rename the variables for my data frame:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'round'                                                                           Any idea how I solve this error?

Comment: Hi Jacob, I tried it again. I forgot to change my df to df_final. Now I see only 157.85. This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are the numbers in CL_total integers or strings (in which case strings cannot be rounded)
Check with `df_final.dtypes`.

```
df_final["CL_total"].astype(int) # conver the strings of CL_total to ints

df_final['CL_total'].iloc[0] == df_final['CL_total'].iloc[0].round(2)
```

[The `astype()` method docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas.Series.astype)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your reply. The CL_Total is a float64